# Django restframework upgrading from 0.4.0 to 3.3.1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've upgraded django restframework from 0.4.0 to 3.3.1 and there's some missing imports I'd like to know the current equivalents. Previously it was `from djangorestframework import` to `from rest_framework import`

```
mixins import ReadModelMixin, PaginatorMixin
views import View, ListModelView, ModelView
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple equivalents. Newest version of DRF is not straightforward compatible with 0.4.0, there was lot of changes and without reading documentation for new DRF you won't be able to migrate properly.

But answering your question, as far as I know , there is no such thing as `ReadModelMixin` anymore. There were replaced with more sophisticated solutions and there is no easy answer for replacing it.

`PaginatorMixin` is also removed, because all default list views have pagination built in and you can swap pagination backeds. See more about pagination in [GenericAPIView attributes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes)

Views were replaced by [Generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) and [Viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) so here you also can't just swap classes.